# Replace underscores with hyphens in Perl Catalyst URLs

Tags: perl, catalyst

We're looking at options for converting CamelCase to `camel-case` and underscores to hyphens and hoping someone can offer some strong examples. (Using hyphens for SEO reasons).

Specifically:

Working on an MMORPG in Catalyst and getting tired of having to write things like this:

```
sub travel_to  ( $self, $c, $star ) : Path('travel-to') Args(1)  { ... }
```

Or this:

```
package Veure::Controller::Area::StorageLocker {
    ....
    sub index ( $self, $c ) : Path('/area/storage-locker') { ... }
}
```

*Update*: Because there's some confusion, I meant that we'd much prefer to have devs write this:

```
# getting rid of Args() would be nice, but sigs don't have introspection
sub travel_to  ( $self, $c, $star ) : Args(1)  { ... }
```

Or this:

```
package Veure::Controller::Area::StorageLocker {
    ....
    sub index ( $self, $c ) { ... }
}
```

This is important because for an SEO standpoint, underscores instead of hyphens can dramatically improve your SEO. By having to do extra grunt work to always force hyphens, developers are forgetting to do this and we keep wasting money going back and having to rewrite code where this caveat was forgotten. This is the sort of thing which we should be able to do automatically.

Comment: I'm not sure of your purpose. Are you saying that you want to avoid having to type the hyphens and want to enter `'TravelTo'` and `'/area/StorageLocker'` and have them converted automatically?

Comment: I understand the question as that he is too lazy to type the same kind of attributes on his subs all the time. Instead, he wants a way to make the Catalyst framework do this dash-behavior automatically. Also see http://blogs.perl.org/mt/mt-search.fcgi?blog_id=11&tag=veure&limit=20 to understand what _Veure_ is.

Comment: @simbabque: It isn't clear to me how the OP's stated intention of converting camel case to snake case and replacing underscores with hyphens helps to solve his frustration in *"having to write things like this"*.  Are we talking about some sort of source code filter, or an IDE macro perhaps? As far as I can tell, `Path` and `Args` should stay unchanged, and I know that Catalyst does some sort of identifier translation in a similar way to `DBIx::Class`, but I'm struggling to imagine how the code in a useful answer would be used by the OP

Comment: @borodin I think he is looking for alternatives to using Path in the way he does. The examples make it clear that it's basically redundant, but for the hyphen replacement. So it's something that can be added to the Catalyst application that makes the use of Path unnecessary but retains the shown functionality. We could theoretically close it as off topic for recommendations but I think it's a rather interesting problem.

Answer (score 3):

I did a bit of digging in the Catalyst sources.

**Cammel case controller names**

You can modify [`class2prefix`](https://metacpan.org/source/JJNAPIORK/Catalyst-Runtime-5.90105/lib/Catalyst/Utils.pm#L112) in [Catalyst::Utils](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Utils#class2prefix-class-case) to change how the controller names translate to the *namespace*.

Here is a very quick hack that demonstrates what is going on with a fresh MyApp created with *catalyst.pl*. I borrowed [Borodin's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37968830/1331451) to implement it.

```
package MyApp::Controller::FooBar;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;
BEGIN { extends 'Catalyst::Controller'; }

{
    require Class::Method::Modifiers;
    require String::CamelCase;

    Class::Method::Modifiers::around(
        'Catalyst::Utils::class2prefix'  => sub {
            my $orig = shift;

            # I borrowed most of this from the original function ...
            my $class = shift || '';
            my $prefix = shift || 0;
            if ( $class =~ /^.+?::([MVC]|Model|View|Controller)::(.+)$/ ) {
                $prefix = $2;
                $prefix =~ s{::}{/}g;

                # ... and this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37968830/1331451
                $prefix = String::CamelCase::decamelize($prefix) =~ tr/_/-/r;
            }

            return $prefix;
        }
    );
}

sub index :Path :Args(0) {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
    $c->response->body('Matched MyApp::Controller::FooBar in FooBar.');
} 

1;
```

I tested this briefly, but cannot guarantee it's not going to break anything else. I believe if it's put into a better place and done in a more appropriate way it could be a viable option.

**Underscores in actions**

This one looks trickier. My best bet is to fiddle with [Catalyst::DispatchType::Path](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::DispatchType::Path) in some way, or create something that installs an ActionClass that modifies it. It's basically replacing the `_` with a `-`. That *thing* could be built around  [`gather_default_action_roles` in Catalyst::Controller](https://metacpan.org/source/JJNAPIORK/Catalyst-Runtime-5.90105/lib/Catalyst/Controller.pm#L381) (maybe as a subclass) to add that one to all actions. **This is highly speculative**.

Comment: the clean way to do it would be to create a new controller subclass, and a new attribute called `Dashy` or whatever you like. Then the controller class would define a `_parse_Dashy_attr` method that returns `(Path => $value =~ s/_/-/gr)` or whatever it likes. That way you can use it selectively without affecting unrelated code that uses `Path`.

Comment: @hobbs you mean a `: Dashy` sub attribute?

Comment: yep. Although I misspoke, of course it needn't use the value passed to the attr, since the point is to save typing, it can use the method name which is passed in as the third arg.

Comment: @hobbs But that would still require any typing. I think having the controller base class automatically adding it to every action that is not `Local` or has a `Path` of its own might be good as well. That would save even more typing, and I figure Veure has quite a bit of those cases.

Comment: Yeah, that's possible, just trying to propose something that fits in a little more with Catalyst philosophy but still reduces the typing and repetition. I guess I should go make my own answer :)

Comment: I'm looking forward to that.

Comment: @simbabque: Since you seem to understand the question better than I do, perhaps you could clarify it for us?

Comment: @Borodin which part? Can you clarify what you want me to clarify? I thought it pretty clear, but you need some Catalyst knowledge for it.:)

Answer (score 2):

CPAN has the [`String::CamelCase`](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::CamelCase) module, which offers a `decamelize` function, after which you will need to convert underscores to hyphens using `tr/_/-/`

I hope this short example helps to answer your question

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use v.14.1;

use String::CamelCase 'decamelize';

for my $s ( 'travel_to', 'Veure::Controller::Area::StorageLocker' ) {
    (my $ss = $s) =~ s|^[\w:]*::Controller(?=::)||;
    $ss =~ s|::|/|g;
    $ss = decamelize($ss) =~ tr/_/-/r;
    say $ss;
}
```

#### output

```
travel-to
/area/storage-locker
```